# "on the horizon" vs. "at the horizon"

Tags: prepositions

> For a small handful of people, that dot **on** the horizon is a place called home.

or

> For a small handful of people, that dot **at** the horizon is a place called home.

What is the difference?

Comment: http://www.dotonthehorizon.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think both are acceptable, however **on** I believe is more common and certainly sounds more natural to me, probably because the perspective it emphasises is more natural:

If you say "on", you are emphasising the perspective that the horizon is a horizontal line **on** which something can sit.

If you say "at", you are emphasising that the horizon is a point in the distance **at** which something can be.

Answer (score 1):

> **on** the horizon

is an expression which can be used to mean **a far off distance**, or for something which is beginning to come into view.

> The boat appeared *on the horizon*.

[image]

BTW on a clear day, for a person of average height, the *horizon* is usually a few miles away.

It can also be used to express a time which is approaching

> The solution to our problem is just *on the horizon*.

Whereas

> **at** the horizon

would usually be understood to mean a *specific location*

> A spaceship will appear motionless *at the event horizon* of a black hole.

[image]

*On* is usually used in this idiomatic phrase.

Comment: Just want to mention that "event horizon" is a technical term of the scientific study of black hole, so its usage may not represent typical ones of the word "horizon" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon).